# I can't get GitVersion to bump versions

Tags: github-actions, gitversion

I'm converting my project from Azure DevOps to GitHub Actions.
I use GitVersion to auto version my builds.

I use GitVersion Mainline mode, and I typically commit with a comment including e.g. `+semver: minor` that is supposed to auto bump the version.

I am using the latest GitVersion 5.5.1, and I changed my `master` branch to `main`, which is supposed to be supported in GitVersion 5.5+.
I don't know if I am screwing something up in the conversion, or if 5.5.1 has a bug.

My Project action config is here:
https://github.com/ptr727/Utilities/blob/main/.github/workflows/BuildPublishPipeline.yml

I don't know if builds can be seen by others, but here is a build output where the minor versions should have been bumped by +semver to at least 1.4.1, not stuck on 1.4.0:
https://github.com/ptr727/Utilities/runs/1437057234

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in 5.5.1.
It requires a few workarounds, use 5.3.7, use action 0.9.7, enable unsecure commands, add main to master regex.

GitVersion.yml:

```
mode: Mainline
next-version: 1.4.0

# 5.5 supports master and main, but 5.5.1 does not work as expected
# https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/2461
# Use 5.3.7, and manually add main to regex
# regex: ^master$|^main$
# gitversion /showconfig

branches:
  master:
    regex: ^master$|^main$
```

GitHub Action:

```
      # Install GitVersion
      # Requires .NET Core 3.1
      # 5.5.1 does not work as expected, use 5.3.x
      # https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/2461
      # master vs. main branch: regex: ^master$|^main$
      # https://github.com/marketplace/actions/gittools
      - name: 'Install GitVersion'
        uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/setup@v0.9.7
        with:
          versionSpec: '5.3.x'

      # Run GitVersion
      - name: 'Run GitVersion Tool'
        id: gitversion
        uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/execute@v0.9.7
        with:
          additionalArguments: '/diag'
        env: 
          # https://github.com/GitTools/actions/issues/255
          # https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/
          ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of using [GitVersion](https://gitversion.net/docs/)

```
jobs:
  create_version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Install GitVersion
        uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/setup@v1.1.1
        with:
          versionSpec: '5.x'
      - name: Determine Version
        id: version_step
        uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/execute@v1.1.1
        with:
          useConfigFile: true
```

And as we have given the option `useConfigFile: true`, it needs a file named `GitVersion.yml` in root folder.

My version of file with minimal changes

```
mode: ContinuousDelivery
increment: Patch
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major|release)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feat|feature|minor)'
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
```

Read this for configuration parameters [GitVersion Incrementing Version](https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/version-increments#manually-incrementing-the-version)